# Selenium WebDriver Multi-Threading & Browser Hiding using Java

Tags: java, testing, selenium, automation, webdriver

I'm using the Java API of the Selenium WebDriver:

1. Is it possible to create multiple instances of the Selenium WebDriver from different threads simultaneously without conflict?
2. How do I change the path of the firefox installation directory that WebDriver uses if I installed firefox in a different directory?
3. How can I hide all the instances of the browsers(e.g firefox) that those threads started?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I can give you an answer to your first question.

Yes, you can run multiple driver instances simultaneously. However it is not recommended to run more than 5 or so instances at once in a single selenium server. [Selenium Grid](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/grid/) was designed specifically for this (it is bundled with the Selenium Server).

Comment: For your second issue and if using Linux you could take a look at the solution proposed at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38768819/399959