# Selenium testing without browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, load-testing

I use Selenium RC for testing. Now to perform a load test, I want to run parallel test cases.
Is there any way to run them without opening a browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide the browser in Selenium RC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418082/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-browser-in-selenium-rc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set up on Centos (do all installation as root)

Install pip Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

```
python get-pip.py
```

Installing selenium
If you have pip on your system, you can simply install or upgrade the Python bindings:
    pip install -U selenium

Alternately, you can download the source distribution from PyPI (e.g. selenium-2.53.1.tar.gz), unarchive it, and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

install the program: pyvirtualdisplay

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay

yum install Xvfb libXfont Xorg
```

Then modify your script to add the bold lines within ** and **

```
**from pyvirtualdisplay import Display**
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class SeleniumDemo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        **self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
        self.display.start()**
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://www.soastastore.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True


    def tearDown(self):`enter code here`
        self.driver.quit()
        ***self.display.stop()***
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

Answer (score 131):

Chrome now has a headless mode:

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
```

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: Simplest answers are usually the best! Thank you.

Comment: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
  warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '

Comment: how can i use this if I additionally want to copy something to clipboard and then paste it? I tried it but it only works when the browser opens

Answer (score 14):

Since PhantomJS has been deprecated, using headless versions of Firefox would be a viable option.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

Comment: this work in my macbook. I wonder why it would discretely open a firefox icon (looks like an idle icon) on the right side of my Dock, but yes you can't see what is happening. So I guess, it is operating headless indeed.

Answer (score 10):

Try this code:

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can run Selenium headless, take a look at this question/answer: [Is it possible to hide the browser in Selenium RC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418082/selenium-can-i-hide-the-browser)

Especially for performance load tests, you should have a look at 
[Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter).

Comment: I already tried Apache JMeter for load testing Of GWT apps. But it not quite successful.

Answer (score 3):

Always follow the Documentation. Here is what [selenium doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver) says. It provide a [standalone jar](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.7/selenium-server-stand%20alone-3.7.1.jar).

- Download the standalone jar. And run it with command

  ```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar
  ```
- Now you will see a stanalone server started.
- Now set up your webdriver like below and rest part will be as it is.

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'htmlunit', 'version': '2', 'javascriptEnabled': True})
  ```
- Summary code will be like.

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', 
  desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'htmlunit', 'version': '2', 
  'javascriptEnabled': True})
  driver.get("http://www.python.org")
  assert "Python" in driver.title
  elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
  elem.clear()
  elem.send_keys("pycon")
  elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
  driver.close()
  ```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but not with the standard firefox driver / chrome / etc.

You would need to install PhantomJS. Just assign your WebDriver to an instance of phantomJS driver:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

If you run your code now, no browser window will be opened.

Comment: the PhantomJS development is now suspended as per @Hunter and yes I can confirm. https://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can import `Options` if you don't want to open a web browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver   # for webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # for implicit and explict waits
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser
```

Then in the code:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```

And continue with the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

requirements:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
pip install selenium
pip install PyVirtualDisplay
```

download chrome driver binary from below link and paste into drivers directory: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

with Display(visible=False, size=(800, 600)):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver')
    browser.get('https://www.example.com')
    print(browser.page_source)
    browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass an argument "headless" to test selenium without opening the browser.

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
```

This code snippet will provide you exactly what you want.