# Declaring driver in python using selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, automated-tests

Syntax to declare driver in Selenium is

**Webdriver driver = new.firefoxdriver()**

Is there any other way to declare driver. The syntax will open the firefox browser. I am trying to declare driver without opening browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium testing without browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593611/selenium-testing-without-browser)

Comment: Why are you trying to declare the driver without opening the browser?

Comment: Try using headless browser then..

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur What is headless browser? How can I use it?

Comment: Actually I need this to accept the alert box pop up. Accept().alert() is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like this

```
wd=webdriver.Firefox()
```

but this will also launch the browser as selenium is designed to work in a web browser, but if you want to test something without launching the browser you can use HTMLUnitDriver, which is a headless browser and used to run test cases without actually launching the browser.