# Scrape website data without opening the browser (python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to iteratively search for 30+ items through a search button in webpage and scrape the related data.

My search items are stored in a list: vol_list

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver path")
driver.get("web url")

for item in vol_list :
mc_search_box = driver.find_element_by_name("search_str")
mc_search_box.clear()
search_box.send_keys(item)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

After search is complete I will proceed to scrape the data for each item and store in array/list.
Is it possible to repeat this process without opening browser for every item in the loop?

Comment: See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593611/selenium-testing-without-browser)-- especially the one by Stéphane Bruckert

Answer (score 1):

You can't use chrome and other browsers without opening it.

In your case, headless browsers should do the job. Headless browsers simulates browser, but doesn't have GUI.

Try ghost driver/ html unit driver/ NodeJS. Then you will have to modify at least this line with the driver you want to use:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver path")
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I have started using PhantomJS()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firefox, you can apply the ***headless*** option:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('your url')
```