# Simulate browser execution to execute a script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to crawl the data at the bottom of [this](https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=IGRUGLIA2#history/s20160101/e20170101/myear) webpage (the historical_table). If I use requests.get it returns the source code of the page, that contains only the script to create the table. The only way I know to crawl it is using selenium.webdriver (so via a browser session); however, this method is slower.

Is there a way to simulate the browser execution of the script without opening a browser session at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593611/selenium-testing-without-browser check this

Comment: No, I'd like to use another tool, not selenium. I'd like to use a requests-like process that gets the HTML of the page AND execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but it means you are writing your own browser which I dont recommend. Use a headless browser instead, like http://phantomjs.org . These are meant to be used this way.