# How to run selenium web driver on the cloud

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm looking to run a selenium webdriver script 24/7 on a cloud service. My biggest confusion is will the executable path to the chromedriver work while my computer is not on. Is this possible?, and if yes, how would I do it?

Answer (score 5):

If a program runs in the cloud it still runs on some kind of server (e.g. a virtual machine, a docker container). So you have to install chromedriver on this server in the cloud. Your program in the cloud will not be able to use chromedriver on your computer (Ok, anything is possible - but this would be very strange).

Here is a similar question about running Selenium without opening a browser window. That is an approach, which will work on a server:
[Selenium testing without browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593611/selenium-testing-without-browser)

Or here is a tutorial to do so:
https://withr.github.io/set-up-selenium-headless-on-ubuntu-16.04/