# Selenium Web-driver tests failing in Test-Controller machine when its not viewed

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am facing a strange problem with my selenium webdriver qa automation project.

FindElementByXPath(element); seems to work fine when running it in my local machine but then does not work when i try to run the same code on test controller machine. Actually it runs fine when you see the tests running on the test controller machine and if you minimize the test controller window it fails the test.

The application uses telerik rad grids. I have implemented a code to right click on grid header. After right clicking on the grid header i am supposed to click on Reset Columns from the context menu. But in this case FindElementByXPath(resetElement); does not work. It works when you view it but does not work when minimize the mstsc window.

The error shown is Open.QA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on element.

How do I solve this ??

Comment: I suppose if it can't see the element, it can't click on it. Don't minimize it?

Comment: @AramKocharyan : That's not a permanent solution is it ?? Tests should run irrespective of whether the user is viewing it or not.

Comment: Not sure there, when I ran mine they were super fast and cool, so I sat there in awe the whole time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418082/selenium-can-i-hide-the-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this issue using javascript to click on the element. here is the code.

```
    var element= driver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementXPath));
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onclick');",  element);
```