# Selenium hide a browser

Tags: java, selenium

I use selenium in my java aplication. I know that it works good. Therefore I would like use my aplication without browser. I use Windows 7 and in future I would like run the selenium server on Windows server 2008. Can you help me?

Comment: You can use HtmlUnitDriver
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver or you can create a windows service for selenium
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418082/selenium-can-i-hide-the-browser