# Alternatives to Coded UI test for Visual Studio

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2013, ui-testing

Im looking for some alternatives for Coded UI test. Unfortunately I'm only running Visual Studio 2013 professional

I have already looked at Selenium for Firefox, but that does not seem to work in my version of Firefox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Selenium or WebBrowser alternative mimic human](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063448/c-sharp-selenium-or-webbrowser-alternative-mimic-human)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test web applications, you can use any of the following:

1. Selenium
2. Cypress.io
3. Nightwatch.js(uses Selenium BTS)

For Windows desktop applications, Microsoft is now supporting Appium based WinAppDriver. For more details, you may check the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver). I also teach a Udemy course on the subject which can be seen here[enter link description here](https://www.udemy.com/course/appium-winappdriver-automation-testing/?referralCode=ED22C3A4CE5BB5E22E53). 
White is another desktop application testing API but I haven't used it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We previously used WebAii to test a complex ASP.NET application and it was successful. I have found out that it is now part of Telerik controls. (I have no affiliation with the company.)

http://www.telerik.com/videos/details/teststudio/webaii-testing-framework-and-nunit

Other than that, keeping the UI as light/dummy as possible and testing beneath it extensively usually worked out better for me.