# Parse html-page with knockout model

Tags: knockout.js, html-agility-pack

I trying to parse html-page with **html agility pack**, and I want to get some value from element, but this value setted in knockout model.

```
//...
function jsCycle(cycleid /* another variables */) {
        this.CycleYearID = ko.observable(cycleid);
        /* another variables */
    };

var c1 = new jsCycle('1edb0cc2-82af-e211-896a-3c4a92dbdc51'/* another variables */); 

ko.applyBindings(c1, $('#BoundCycleAreaOne')[0]);
jsModel.cycles.push(c1);
//...
```

I can get `'#BoundCycleAreaOne'` element:

```
var period = document.QuerySelectorAll("#BoundCycleAreaOne");
```

but also I need his `CycleYearID`. How I can get it?

Comment: You should make a fiddle that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have list of BoundCycleAreas and I want to get CycleYearID of one and send it via POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible using `HtmlAgilityPack` and the `.html` file alone.

While `HtmlAgilityPack` can parse HTML, it can not run JS code at all.

You can use a tool like [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449066/browserless-web-scraping-of-ajax-page) to wait for a given amount of time until KnockoutJS populated the page and then grab the source and feed it to `HtmlAgilityPack`.