# How to work with selenium without displaying the browser in the screen?

Tags: selenium

I want to scrab some web information generated by JavaScript functions by using selenium. But I don't want to display in my screen the automated work on the browser. How can I do that?

Comment: a lot of answers out there that answer this particular question. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/running-webdriver-without-opening-actual-browser-window http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418082/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-browser-in-selenium-rc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180428/can-selenium-webdriver-open-browser-windows-silently-in-background

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the operating system you are using. For Linux based systems you can use Xvfb. For windows you have options like using HTMLUnitDriver provided by Selenium, or you can use PhantomJS as browser. With latest versions of selenium webdriver, phantomjs bindings are also available.