# python urllib2, No proper response

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to get some data from website, for example : image URL, Page Title etc.

But response is not good.

Code :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = [
    "https://www.nfm.com/DetailsPage.aspx?productid=43382514"
]

# Image URLhttps://www.nfm.com/GetPhoto.ashx?ProductID=43382514&Size=L


def get_data(url):
    user_agent = '"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"'
    headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    page = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
    page2 = urllib2.urlopen(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page2, 'html.parser')
    print soup.prettify('latin-1')
    # img_url = https://www.nfm.com/GetPhoto.ashx?ProductID=43382514&Size=L

for i in url_list:
    get_data(i)
```

Result is:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.cookie="ns_cls="+"w:"+screen.width+",h:"+screen.height+",ua:"+escape(navigator.userAgent)
window.location.href = "**https://www.nfm.com/DetailsPage.aspx?productid=43382514**"
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

So, I am getting this HTML page. Includes the URL i am calling through python script (urllib2 module)

Even Response Module of python react as same!

I don't know how to get proper response!!
Please Help !

Comment: Because that is what it gets, the information you retrieve for the page is correct. Did you try blocking your cookies in your web browser when you access to that page? Maybe you should try another approach to get the content.

Comment: How @VíctorM ?? Please give me some idea

Comment: I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418082/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-browser-in-selenium-rc. You can use it with BeautifulSoup and get the content

Comment: You could simply forge the cookie by yourself and add it to your header in the urrlib request. The recipe is right in the response

Comment: @VíctorM  Selenium is super slow!!! I need to work on urllib2

Comment: @shivshankar then set the cookies as Abaddon666 wrote

Comment: Use `requests` module and set the cookies value: `cookies = {'ns_cls': 'w:800,h:600,ua:' + user_agent}`. Then call it with `requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)`. Please remove the simple or double quotes in the `user_agent` variable.

Comment: @VíctorM, Its working Bro :) Thankyou So much